# Is there a term for a section of an article which contains a quote or snippet from the main text?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes in articles in newspapers / magazines / websites there will be a small section separate from the main body of text that contains a short line - often a quote - which is either representative of the article or an interesting angle.

For example:

[image: PC Gamer article]

Here the quote in the box on the right hand side is an example of what I am looking for a term for.

It could be referred to as a **blockquote** (but those could be in-line with the text) or a **figure** (but those could be graphics to illustrate an article) or an **excerpt** (but those are broad eg a read aloud *excerpt* from a book, etc).

Is there a term that is specific to these small vignettes that appear with a body of text, but are presented separately to the body of it? Perhaps a technical term used by those in publishing / layout design / journalism?

There is a similar concept of a [whole topic being 'vignetted'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334021/word-for-a-vignette-on-a-specific-topic-within-a-book), for example in a box or panel, but I am interested specifically in a quote being set off from the main body of text.

Comment: Related (loosely, but might be of interest to visitors) [Word for a ‘vignette’ on a specific topic within a book](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334021/word-for-a-vignette-on-a-specific-topic-within-a-book)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Great suggestion, one could easily be searching for one and get  the other instead, I've added a sentence to note the similarity and difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is called [pull quote](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote):

> *In graphic design, a **pull quote (also known as a lift-out pull quote)** is a key phrase, quotation, or excerpt that has been pulled from an article and used as a page layout graphic element, serving to entice readers into the article or to highlight a key topic.*
>
> It is typically placed in a larger or distinctive typeface and on the same page. Pull quotes are often used in magazine and newspaper articles, annual reports, and brochures, as well as on the web. They can add visual interest to text-heavy pages with few images or illustrations.

(Wikipedia)

> A technique traditional to print is the [pull quote,](http://htmldog.com/techniques/pullquotes/) a snippet of content that stands out from its surroundings to grab a reader’s attention as they scan pages.

[image]

(htmldog.com/techniques/pullquotes/)

Comment: Spot on! My brain would never have got there but this is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks :)